# JavaScript audio duration display issue in php table

Tags: javascript, php

What i want to achieve is that our table show the duration of audio. But it is only updating the Data in First Row only.

What i have done so far is 
 - First show data from mysql databse in table 
 - List item from that table

```
UserID
Name
Path
IsDir
edit
Duration
```

These are the table columns in my table, every column is showing the right data but The Duration  column is updating in 1st row only

[Here is the image of current table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOOV6.png)

Now My `<tr>` code is

```
       <tbody>
<?php
$count=1;
$sel_query="Select * from table_name where isdir=0 ORDER BY id desc;";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sel_query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
<tr><td align="center"><?php echo $count; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo str_replace(' ', '%20', ($row["path"])); ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $row["isdir"]; ?></td>
<td align="center">

<audio id="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" controls>
  <source src=../..<?php echo str_replace(' ', '%20', ($row["path"])); ?> type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
</td>

<td align="center">
<body onload="myFunction<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>();">
<audio id="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" controls>
  <source src=../..<?php echo str_replace(' ', '%20', ($row["path"])); ?> type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<p id="<?php echo $row["name"]; ?>"></p>

<script>
function myFunction<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>() {
    var x<?php echo $row["id"]; ?> = document.getElementById("<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>").duration;
    document.getElementById("<?php echo $row["name"]; ?>").innerHTML = x<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>;
}
</script>
</body>

</td>
<td><a href="newadd.php?source=<?php echo $row["path"]; ?>&title=<?php echo $row["name"]; ?>">Edit</a>
</td>
<td align="center">
<a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>">Delete</a>
</td>
</tr>
<?php $count++; } ?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: This is the same id _demo_ for each line. You need to make it unique.

Comment: i have updated my code please check

Comment: You can not just output additional `body` elements inside table cells, and hope to get multiple load events to fire that way ... So the first thing you need to do is stop creating ridiculously invalid HTML. Before you manage that first step, there's not much point in trying to operate on the whole thing with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested but something like that might do the trick:

```
<?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($nquery)) { ?>
  <tr>
    <!-- ... -->
    <td><a id="link<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"
           href="newadd.php?source=<?php echo $row["path"]; ?>&title=<?php echo $row["name"]; ?>&duration=">Edit</a> 
    </td>
    <td>
      <audio id="myAudio<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"
             onloadedmetadata="myFunction(<?php echo $row['id'] ?>);"
             controls>
         <source src=../..<?php echo str_replace(' ', '%20', ($row["path"])); ?> type="audio/mpeg">
      </audio>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p id="demo<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
<?php } ?>

  <script>
    function myFunction(id) {
      var x = document.getElementById("myAudio" + id).duration;
      document.getElementById("demo" + id).innerHTML = x;
      var a = document.getElementById("link" + id);
      a.href += x;
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: Thanks ,it worked perfect for me, But i wonder How can i pass the Duration value to the next page when i click `EDIT` For now i am able to pass `id` and `title` .

Comment: `<td><a href="newadd.php?source=<?php echo $row["path"]; ?>&title=<?php echo $row["name"]; ?>&duration=?">Edit</a>
</td>` Like this so that at place of `?`  i'll have my duration  of that particular audio .

Comment: Thanks a lot Saved Lots of my time :)

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing in the row ID to the function. It's outside of the brackets in both the call to the function, and when your declaring the parameters.

So instead of:

```
onload="myFunction<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>();"
function myFunction<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>()
```

Do:

```
onload="myFunction(<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>);"
function myFunction(<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>)
```